# Flutter Application Runs in Web Debug but the build is stuck on the splash screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-chrome

I succesfully ran my build in chrome in debug mode, but when running `flutter build web` and opening the index.html, the build is stuck at the splash screen.
The error i get in the console is:

> Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/.../build/web/assets/FontManifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Flutter doctor sais Chrome is fine

[image: Flutter doctor sais Chrome is fine]

Anyone knows how to fix?
I initialised Firebase and use the SDK:

```
<script type="module">
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
      import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-analytics.js";
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "...",
        measurementId: "..."
      };
    
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
    
    </script>
```

maybe it has something to do with firebase?
Hope anyone can help